# Solving Codility Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I tried the sample demo at Codility website, and posted my solution but I've a simple mistake but couldn't determine it.

The problem is described here (The problem is only described please don't care about the analysis there as that wasn't not my solution)

http://codility.com/cert/view/certHNPV9B-7M4GAQR985B54VYF/details

my solution is here:

```
public static int min_router_peripherality ( int[] T ) {
        // write your code here
        int sum=0;

        for(int i=0;i<T.length;i++) sum+= T[i];

        int min = sum;
        int index = 0;
        int array [] = new int [T.length];

        for(int i=0;i<T.length;i++) { 

             min = sum -T[i];
             array[i] = min;
        }
        int x = array[0];

        for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++)
        {
            if (array[i]<x)
            {
                x = array[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }
```

Comment: I removed the apparently incorrect C++ tag.

Comment: Time complicity of your solution is O(N), but you've got timeout error. Are you sure that you submit this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see as mistakes are the following:

```
for(int i=0;i<T.length;i++) 
    sum+= T[i];
```

Here you treat `T[i]` like some weight. But Node-Ids are no weights. Summing up node ids is useless.

Then: The text says: "if T[P] = Q and P ≠ Q, ...". I don't see anything which takes this into account.

Then: Not understanding the algorithm I tried a simple "line" like this:

```
int[] T = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9};
```

The result is `8`. But in a line the result should be somewhere in the middle.

**Therefore I doubt that the linked page shows the results of the code you have posted.**

Comment: You are correct. I've edited the question. I just posted the problem description link, but people considered the analysis there as it was related to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the results I would say that your program is correct, but too slow to successfully complete all test cases. So you need to come up with better algorithm.

EDIT: As Ivan Benko Ivan Benko noted, your solution is O(N), so i looked at your code and I came up with a following input:

```
{ 4, 9, 4, 9, 4, 4, 8, 9, 0, 0 }
```

Although it is not the example input, it does describe the same network as in the task description. So the output should be same, but your solution gives a different answer.

Comment: The result mentioned in the above link isn't related to the above code. I just wanted to mention the algorithm problem using that link only.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was look at your code, and the first thing I noticed is that it doesn't look like you need that `array` array at all, or that third `for` loop.  The second `for` loop can just keep track of the lowest `min` value it generates as it goes, along with the index associated with that lowest `min` value, rather than storing all the values and making a second run like you're doing now.

**Edit:**
Like everyone else, I assumed that your link was to your own results. I'm not going to post an answer, because I think you're supposed to come up with that yourself.  However, it looks to me like you got confused where they said "find the sum of distances to all other nodes", and that might be why you're starting off summing up the entire array.  The array they're passing into your function isn't a set of distances by any means.  It's a list of existing connections.  If the first element (the one at the 0 index) in the array is a 5, then that means Router 0 has a connection to Router 5.  So it looks to me like you're approaching it all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Two adjacent node has a one edge and its weight is 1.